# How can I handle the presentation of a research problem?

Tags: ds.algorithms, graph-algorithms, research-practice

I recently discovered a more efficient algorithm for a problem that was published in a specialized journal and presented in a rather concrete way that is related to its application.
I abstracted that problem definition from the original application-specific definitions but I am unsure how to proceed in my presentation of the problem.
I initially considered providing a description of how my definitions correspond to the original definitions but this is too much a hassle for me.

Will it be considered acceptable if I just present my own abstracted definitions in the paper as I plan to submit it to a general algorithms journal?

Comment: I would say it really depends on how natural your abstraction of the problem is regarding to the original formulation. Presenting an abstract algorithm in a too abstract way may seems unnatural to the reader and people will just assume it to be yet another useless algorithm for a fun theoretical problem someone came up with. I would at least informally explain how your approach can be seen as a generalization of the more applied version. This can only make your contribution stronger and open the way for interesting collaborations with more applied people.